# Returning templates

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to return a template?

This is what I've been trying, but this isn't working.

```
template<int degree>
class Polynomial
{
public:

   ... ususal stuff ...

   // Polynimal<degree - 1>
   Polynomial derivative() { /* returns a different template */ }

};


int main()
{
   Polynomial<3> cubic;
   Polynomial<2> parabola;

   parabola = cubic.derivative();
}
```

Is this possible? What little nugget am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the member-function a function template:

```
template<int ret_degree>
Polynomial<ret_degree> derivative() { /* returns a different template */ }
```

Or, if you know the degree of the return-polynomial, you can do something like this:

```
Polynomial<degree-1> derivative() { /* returns a different template */ }
```

Answer (score 4):

`degree` is known at compile time, so you can use `degree -1` as value argument in the return type:

```
template<int degree>
class Polynomial
{
public:

   Polynomial<degree-1> derivative() 
   {  
         Polynomial<degree-1> d;
         //...
         return d;
   }
};
int main() {
         Polynomial<3> cubic;
         Polynomial<2> parabola;
         parabola = cubic.derivative();
        return 0;
}
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/44Pc7

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want this :

```
template<int degree>
class Polynomial
{
public:

   ... ususal stuff ...

   // Polynimal<degree - 1>
   Polynomial< degree-1 > derivative() {
     Polynomial< degree-1 > res;
     //assign values
     return res
   }

};
```

Make sure that in you specialization for `Polynomial<0>` the method `derivative` doesn't exits.

Comment: Why derivative of `Polynomial<0>` doesn't exist?

Comment: Assuming I remember my calculus properly, if Polynomial<2> is x^2, Polynomial<1> is 2x, Polynomial<0> is 2. I suppose you could take the derivative of a constant, but it's not very useful.

Comment: @Nawaz: Anyway a specialization makes sense, as the derivate of a constant does not decrease the degree.